# Are there any programming languages that support xml natively?

Tags: xml, programming-languages, native

If there are any then how deeply is xml integrated into language? What primitives are used to manipulate xml document?

PS. I'm not interested in declarative languages such as SQL, XPath, XSLT :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash's ActionScript 3.0 and JavaScript (ECMAScript languages) are also integrated with XML by [E4X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML).
So code looks something like this (altough this is a simple example and cooler stuff is possible):

```
var sales = <sales vendor="John">
    <item type="peas" price="4" quantity="6"/>
    <item type="carrot" price="3" quantity="10"/>
    <item type="chips" price="5" quantity="3"/>
  </sales>;

alert( sales.item.(@type == "carrot").@quantity );
alert( sales.@vendor );
for each( var price in sales..@price ) {
  alert( price );
}
```

Here are [Adobe's docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ff5.html) for working with XML in AS3.0.

Answer (score 10):

VB.NET 9.0 has [XML literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/xml-literals/) which seems like what you're looking for.
This example taken from [Imran Shaik blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20210120191926/http://geekswithblogs.net/Silverlight2/archive/2008/03/30/xml-literals-and-embedded-expressions.aspx)

```
    <WebMethod()> _
Public Function AllCountriesUsingXMLLiterals() As String

    Dim sud As New CountryDataSetTableAdapters.CountryTableTableAdapter

    Dim XDataSet As New CountryDataSet.CountryTableDataTable

    sud.Fill(XDataSet)

    Dim XDoc = _
        <Countries xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Schema/Countries">
            <%= From country In XDataSet Select <Country Code=<%= country.CountryISO %> Name=<%= country.CountryName %>/> %>
        </Countries>

    Return XDoc.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: I loved it when they introduced this in VB.NET 9... finally something to show to C# developers and make them say, "actually, that's would be quite nice to have in C#..."

Answer (score 4):

Powershell has some niceties in dealing with XML, mainly that a node gets dynamic properties representing its sub-nodes. So given the XML

```
<foo>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
</foo>
```

an XML object created from this has a "foo" property and the object returned by that has a "bar" property.

```
> $x=[xml]"<foo><bar moo='meh'/><bar meow='bleh'/></foo>"
> $x.foo

bar
---
{bar, bar}

> $x.foo.bar[0]

moo
---
meh

> $x.foo.bar[1]

meow
----
bleh
```

Very handy at times.

Comment: subject says 'programming languages'

Comment: XSLT _is_ a programming language - it's Turing-complete (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_complete).

Comment: yep, my bad. I actually ment 'declarative'. I've updated my question

Answer (score 2):

Groovy and Scala have XML literal support, though I think this is generally a really stupid idea.

Answer (score 2):

javascript，see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Processing_XML_with_E4X#Creating_an_XML_object)

Answer (score 1):

Flex and Action Script.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you mean by deeply integrated?  .net comes with an XML namespace and various classes for dealing with XML documents...

Comment: It means what subject says. Native integration does not imply that you're required to use a set of classes to perform simple/trivial operations on xml document.

Answer (score 0):

[XQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) ? From the linked article:

> XQuery provides the means to extract
>   and manipulate data from XML documents
>   or any data source that can be viewed
>   as XML, such as relational databases
>   or office documents.

It supports for-loops, whiles, let, ordering etc.

Comment: yes, but it is rather declarative language than algorithmic one

Comment: :) I don't dislike them, they're cool, but the question was about algorithmic languages like Java...

Answer (score 0):

[Ballerina](https://ballerina.io/) programming language has builtin language support for XML(creating, parsing, and manipulating XML). See the [documentation for xml](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/xml-data-model).